# How does jQuery have the $ object constructor and the methods associated with the $?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How is it that jQuery can do `$("#foo").addClass("bar")` and `$.ajax()`?

I'm creating a micro javascript framework and want to create a new instance of an object, such as `$("#hello")`. With this object there are associated methods, such as `addClass`, `css`, etc, just like with jQuery. So I could do something like

```
$("#foo").addClass("remove").css("color", "red");
```

I have been successful in creating this. However, when I want to call a method from this object, such as `$.ajax`, the constructor function is overwritten, and I can call $.ajax, but not $("#foo").

Basically, how can jQuery do both?

Comment: jQuery uses black magic.  Seriously though, good question +1

Comment: I think you can learn a lot by looking at the jQuery source code.

Comment: @FelixKling you also learn a lot of "Oh I shouldn't do that"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK, the `$` function is not only a function but an object, like all functions. So it can have methods. That's all that `ajax` is, a method of the `$` function. So we can start off by doing this:

```
$ = function(obj) {
  // some code 
};
$.ajax = function (arg1, arg2) {
  // some ajax-y code
};
```

So far so good. Now, what on earth do we put in the `$` function? Well it has to return an object and that object has to have some nice methods defined on it. So we'll need a constructor function (to give us new objects) and a prototype (to provide the nifty methods for those objects).

```
$ = function(obj) {
  var myConstructor = function (obj) {
    this.wrappedObj = obj;
  };

  myConstructor.prototype = {
    niftyMethod: function () {
      // do something with this.wrappedObj
      return this; // so we can chain method calls
    },
    anotherNiftyMethod: function (options) {
      // do something with this.wrappedObj and options
      return this; 
    }
  };

  return new myConstructor(obj);
};
```

So there we have it. We can do this:

```
var mySnazzObject = $("whatever");
mySnazzObject.niftyMethod().anotherNiftyMethod(true);
```

And we can do this:

```
$.ajax("overthere.html", data);
```

Obviously jQuery does a heck of a lot more than that, and it does it in some really impressive ways, but that's the general idea.

**UPDATE**: AS @Raynos was kind enough to observe without supplying a constructive answer, my original code would create the prototype ad infinitum. So we make use of an anonymous autoexecuting function to declare the constructor and prototype separately:

```
(function () {
  var myConstructor = function (obj) {
    this.wrappedObj = obj;
  };

  myConstructor.prototype = {
    niftyMethod: function () {
      // do something with this.wrappedObj
      return this; // so we can chain method calls
    },
    anotherNiftyMethod: function (options) {
      // do something with this.wrappedObj and options
      return this; 
    }
  };

  var $ = function(obj) {
    return new myConstructor(obj);        
  };

  $.ajax = function (arg1, arg2) {
    // some ajax-y code
  };

  window.$ = $;  
}());
```

Comment: What's the point of the prototype when your creating a new prototype object each time `$` gets called.

Comment: @Raynos: there you go, I oversimplified.

Answer (score 16):

```
$ = function(arg) { console.log("$ function called with " + arg); }
$.ajax = function(arg) {console.log("$.ajax called with " + arg);}
$('foo');
$.ajax('bar');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ac7nx/

I don't think there's any magic here. `$` is just a name for the global function. Just keep in mind that in javascript, functions are first class objects that can have their own properties, including sub-functions, which is what `$.ajax` is.

Since you mentioned the constructor function, I should note that there are no OO objects being used here, just regular functions (no `new` keyword), so constructor functions don't play into this.  If you are using the `new` keyword, that is probably where you are getting confused.  If you want `$('#foo')` to return a new object, then inside the `$` function's code you should create a new object using `new` and return that, which is what jQuery does, but the `$` function itself is not a constructor and should not be called with `new`.  Or in the case of something like `$('#someID')`, inside that function jQuery is getting an element object from the DOM and then returning that object, but still `$` is just a regular function  whose return value is an object, not a constructor function.

Answer (score 1):

**Two different things:**

`$.ajax` is a prototyped function of jQuery called ajax.

While `$`('foo') is a **call** of the jQuery function and depending on the type of foo it reacts in different ways. At http://api.jquery.com/jQuery you can see that jQuery (almost the same as $) can react on three different types: selectors, html or callbacks.

Comment: `$.ajax` isn't prototyped. It's just a property on a single instance of an object (a Function). The prototyped functions are the ones that are accessible from the object that the jQuery function returns.

Answer (score 0):

You can imitate the magic jQuery behaviour as following:

```
//define
var _$ = {};
var $ = function(selector) {
           _$.html = function(args) {
                    alert("Doing the method 'html' with arguments " + args 
                           + " for selector " + selector);
                    return _$; //needed for pipeline
        };
        return _$; 
};

$.ajax = function(args){alert("Doing the method 'ajax' "); }

//and try
$("selector1").html("args1").html("args2");
$.ajax("args2");
```